# I'm working on heterogenous list that uses std::variant. Is there a way to initialize it every time with a custom set of types for std::variant?

Tags: c++, oop, std

...or to quickly change types inside `std::variant` in source code.

Below is the code inside header files for the list itself and its container-element.

```
// HVector.hh
class HVector: public std::vector<HVElem>
{
public:
    HVector();
    void push(std::variant<Party, Loot> newData);
    void show();
};

//HVElem.hh
class HVElem
{
public:
    HVElem( std::variant<Party, Loot> newData );
    ~HVElem();
    std::variant<Party, Loot> getData();
private:
    std::variant<Party, Loot> data;
};
```

I'm worried that when I have to change the set of types that `HVector` can take I'll have manually go through a lot of code changing contents inside "<>" of each `std::variant`.

1. Is this just a bad idea of using `std::variant` in this case?
2. If yes, should I use templates or `std::any`?
3. Is there a way to store types and pass them into `HVector` during initialization?
4. Are refactoring tools a solution to the problem?

Comment: You could use a  type alias (`typedef` or `using`) to ensure you only need to change the template parameters in one spot

Comment: What's`HVElem`?

Comment: No, sorry. C++ does not work this way. In C++, the types of all objects are fixed at compile-time. A randomly-chosen `int` can be somehow transformed to a `long`, at runtime. Ditto for any classes, like `std::variant`.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Sorry, I didn't notice that I pasted the same block twice. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is this just a bad idea of using std::variant in this case?

There is too little context, so I have to assume that you are using `std::variant` because `std::variant` is what you need.

> 2. If yes, should I use templates or std::any?

`std::any` is for something very different. `std::variant` is for a limited set of types, `std::any` is for any type. Pick one or the other depending on what you actully need, not based on easier refactoring or the like.

> 3. Is there a way to store types and pass them into HVector during initialization?

You can use an alias:

```
using my_variant = std::variant<Party,Loot>;
```

If you like you can make the classes templates and provide the variant type as parameter:

```
template <typename T>
class HVector: 
{
public:
    HVector();
    void push(T newData);
    void show();
};
```

this will be more flexible but isn't really necessary.

> 4. Are refactoring tools a solution to the problem?

Once you have the alias `my_variant` and you use that consistently throughout your code, you only have to change it in one single place.

PS: Publicly inheriting from standard containers is often not a good idea. It can be done right, but you have to be careful. I allowed myself to simply ignore that part in above example, because it is only remotely related to the question.

PPS: The situation with `std::variant` is a bit similar to `std::pair`. What I mean is that genericity comes at the price of not meaningful names. Even if you use that variant in only one single place in your code, you should give it a meaningful name. When reading your code, I don't understand what a `std::variant<Party,Loot>` really is. Would be different with an alias that tells me something about the meaning. I didn't know what is a good name. `my_variant` certainly isn't one.